# Undefined index - strange?

Tags: php, warnings, undefined-index

I experience something strange with an undefined index..

```
$vatcode = 'U25';
echo $this->vatcode_ids['U25']."\n";
echo $this->vatcode_ids[$vatcode]."\n";

foreach($this->vatcode_account_ids as $id => $vatcode){
    echo $vatcode."\n";
    echo $this->vatcode_ids[$vatcode]; // undefined index
}
```

this returns:

```
681
681
U25  

Notice: Undefined index: U25   in /var/www/.....php on line 64
```

I don't get it?!

Comment: Maybe you meant `$this->vatcode_ids[$id]` instead?

Comment: can you post a var_dump of arrays?

Comment: What does the `$this->vatcode_account_ids` array look like?

Comment: What's the relation between vatcode_account_ids with vatcode_ids?

Comment: got it.. there were som whitespaces in the `$vatcode` var.. kappa.. create a answer

Comment: use [trim()](http://php.net/trim) for removing unwanted whitespaces at the beginning/end

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From empty line printed before Notice massage i assume your $vatcode variable contains some ending new line character. If so it does not match any key in $this->vatcode_ids array.

You should use some trimming function as Dan Lee suggested in comments.